# Is Ubuntu suitable for an embedded system?

Tags: c, embedded-system

I am a beginner. I've heard a lot about Ubuntu, so I want to know if it's the perfect OS for me. I will be using it to learn embedded Linux and programming microcontrollers in C. Can I go with Ubuntu? Please give me your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn’t make sense to run an embedded distribution on a work station, nor a workstation distribution on an embedded device. A PC running Ubuntu desktop would work great as a work station for programming your micro-controllers.

The Ubuntu Software center has loads of software you can start with like Arduino IDE (integrated development environment), or programs that could help you with circuit simulation and or circuit board design. I prefer synaptic to view available packages. If you find something on the net that isnt available through either the software center or synaptic but runs on linux, its often easy to install anyways.

Comment: Thank you Colyn1337 and Keith Reynolds..appreciate your replies,and yes i decided to use Ubuntu but i don't know how easy it is going to be for me to shift from windows to Ubuntu.Hoping for the best.Again thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu system requirements are:

700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
512 MiB RAM (system memory)
5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

You'll want to compare those requirements to whatever platform you're choosing.  The Raspberry Pi will run Fedora and Fedora is ideal for its platform due to its lower system reqs (than ubuntu).

If you're wanting to working with something like Arduino, there's a stand alone scripter/compiler provided by Arduino (which will run on the Ubuntu OS).

Short answer is simply this:  It depends on the hardware.

Comment: Thank you Colyn1337 and Keith Reynolds..appreciate your replies,and yes i decided to use Ubuntu but i don't know how easy it is going to be for me to shift from windows to Ubuntu.Hoping for the best.Again thank you guys

Comment: @chilledout Don't worry, you'll do fine!  It's an adventure I hope you'll enjoy.  I personally believe that Ubuntu has the richest user interface available for a Linux distro.  You can't go wrong with Ubuntu.  Plus, there's always this site for questions ;]

Comment: Re: the Raspberry Pi. The reason Ubuntu doesn't run there isn't so much system requirements but that Ubuntu only supports the ARMv7 processor architecture and the Pi has an ARMv6 chip. For instance, Ubuntu will happily run on a Beagle Bone: http://embeddedprogrammer.blogspot.com/2012/10/beaglebone-installing-ubuntu-1210.html